# Can I have multiple commands run in a manifest.yml file?

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I have a question about manifest.yml files, and the command argument. I am trying to run multiple python scripts, and I was wondering if there was a better way that I can accomplish this?

command: python3 CD_Subject_Area.py python3 CD_SA_URLS.py

Please let me know how I could call more than one script at a time. Thanks!

Comment: There's a handful of ways you can make something run. What is the intent of these scripts? Do they run forever? or are they short term tasks that run and exit? Should they run at the same time or run in that sequence?

Comment: Daniel, they are running Microsoft SQL Merge statements. They are short term, and then they exit. It shouldn't matter how they run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a couple of short-term (ie. run and eventually exit) commands you would want to use Cloud Foundry tasks. The reason to use tasks over adding a custom command into manifest.yml or a Procfile is because the tasks will only run once.

If you add the commands above, as you have them, they may run many times. This is because an application on Cloud Foundry will run and should execute forever. If it exits, the platform considers it to have crashed and will restart it. Thus when your task ends, even if it is successful (i.e. exit 0), the platfrom still thinks it's a crash and will run it again, and again, and again. Until you stop your app.

With a task, you'd do the following instead:

1. `cf push` your application. This will start and stage the application. You can simply leave the command/`-c` argument as empty and do not include a Procfile[1][2]. The push will execute, the buildpack will run and stage your app, and then it will fail to start because there is no command. That is OK.
2. Run `cf stop` to put your app into the stopped state. This will tell the platform to stop trying to restart it.
3. Run `cf run-task <app-name> <command>`. For example, `cf run-task my-cool-app "python3 CD_Subject_Area.py"`. This will execute the task in it's own container. The task will run to completion. Looking at `cf tasks <app-name>` will show you the result. Using `cf logs <app-name> --recent` will show you the output.

You can then repeat this to run any number of other tasks commands. You don't need to wait for the original one to run. They will all execute in separate containers so one task is totally separated from another task.

---

[1] - An alternative is to set the command to `sleep 99999` or something like that, don't map a route, and set the health check type to `process`. The app should then start successfully. You'll still stop it, but this just avoids an unseemly error.

[2] - If you've already set a command and want to back that out, remove it from your `manifest.yml` and run `cf push -c null`, or simply `cf delete` your app and `cf push` it again. Otherwise, the command will be retained in Cloud Controller, which isn't what you'd want.