# how to run a one-off task on cloudfoundry to upload data before starting Python app

Tags: cloud-foundry

Hi this is my first experience trying to deploy a Python app on cloud using CF. I am having issues deploying my app; I sincerely appreciate if anyone can help me or point me to the right direction to solve the issue.

The main problem is the app that I am trying to deploy is large size due to a lot of python dependencies. The size of my app directory is 200 Kb. The first error I observed was: Staging fails due to "Failed to upload payload for droplet" . I think the reason is when all Python dependencies are downloaded from requirements.txt file and finally the droplet is created its size is too large for upload. The droplet size=982. 3 Mb.

The first solution I tried was vendoring app where I created a vendor directory containing all python dependencies but the size of vendor directory was greater that 1Gb, which causes the upload size exceed 1Gb limit and leads to failure in uploading app files.

The second solution I am working on is to upload all installed Python libraries on an object store (in my case S3 bucket which is bounded to my app) and then download the dependencies folder called Pypackages to the app's root directory: /home/vcap/app, so I want to have /home/vcap/app/Pypackages exist before my app starts on the cloud. But I couldn't do it successfully yet. I have included a python script in my app directory which downloads files from S3 bucket successfully. (I have put the correct absolute path for download in downloadS3.py script ie, /home/vcap/app/Pypackages) I want to run this script using "python downloadS3.py" as a one-off task.  First I tried the solution here : [Can I have multiple commands run in a manifest.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488560/can-i-have-multiple-commands-run-in-a-manifest-yml-file)
and although I can see the status of the task is SUCCEED via '$cf tasks my-app-name' , /home/vcap/app/Pypackages does not exist.

I also tried to run one-off task as the steps below:

1-
`$ cf push -c 'python downloadS3.py && sleep infinity' -i 1 --no-route`

2-
`$ cf push -c 'null'` 
I have printed the contents of /home/vcap/app on my app, ie when app is started and I enter the url in my browser (I don't know what is the right way to see the contents of root directory). Anyway, the problem is Pypackages are not downloaded to the correct root directory. I am not sure if I am running the one-off task in a wrong way or if there is a better solution to make my app work.
I appreciate any helps! (edited)

Comment: Did you try increasing the size of the disk quota for your app? When you push it is the `-k` argument. Try using `cf push -k 2G` or 4G (whatever your system is configured to allow). All of the python packages you install plus your app, everything must fit within the quota defined. If you have a 1G default disk quota, which is common, you might be bumping into that.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Thank you. In manifest.yaml I have set disk_quota: 8196MB. I just tried your solution `cf push my-app -k 8G` and still see the same error: "Failed to upload payload for droplet. Uploaded build artifacts cache (1023.4M). Uploading failed". I have checked log files, but I still don't know why I see this error. What is the reason that upload fails?

Comment: OK, it was worth checking the disk quota, but I think @arjain13 has it right. There are limits set by your operations team. These help keep the system functional. You are hitting one of those limits. You need to talk with your operations team and ask them to look into this error & increase the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego Cells stage apps and upload droplet to blobstore via cloud controller, the max file can be uploaded is configurable at Ops Manager > TAS for VMs > Application Developer Control > Maximum File Upload Size (MB), default is 1024MB. Seems this is causing restriction, if you can get it increased with your admin help...

Tasks run in their own containers so possibly not an option. I think Python buildpack collects and install the packages before creating the droplet, so don't think copying packages directly to /app directory will be of much help.

If you have data files then you can use `.profile` file and do some scripting to copy them from S3 or server/NFS location into the /app directory. Something like

```
wget http://s3.location.com/data_files
cp data_files /home/vcap/app/
```

But if all these are packages and increasing the size is not feasible then you may need to look to break the app..

Comment: Thanks. My requirements.txt file includes index-url option and is downloading packages from PyPi server. But during the deployment all packages are downloaded and this increases the size of droplet, right?

Comment: Updated a bit, hope it helps.